# Monkey throwing security exception even though they are disabled

Tags: android, testing, android-securityexception, monkey

He everyone, I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
```

and Im not sure where its coming from as the app im testing doesnt use `android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`
anywhwere

Maybe it is a 3rd party library somewhere.

I disabled security exceptions with

```
adb shell monkey -p package.name --ignore-security-exceptions  -v -v 15000
```

but it still throws the exception.

Any help with this will be appreciated, thank you for your time

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I just started monkey testing in an Android 12 emulator and got this exception.

Comment: No, I'm hoping someone comes along with a solution, for now I just paused using it. If you figure it out let me know, I'll do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely a permission issue within the program "Monkey" itself in which, is conflicting with the Android permission system. It appears to be the same type of error that would occur in Windows if you tried to run a program that required administrative rights.

If possible, try running as admin.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run monkey as admin? I already tried adb root